# Java Recursive method that accepts an array then returns true when each element is twice the value of the previous element

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am writing a java recursive method that accepts an array and returns that true when each element is twice the value of the previous element. I can't figure out the base case yet, because it is returning true for each case. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class testRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(isDouble(new int[]{2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 5));

    }
    public static boolean isDouble(int[] array,int i) {
        //base case
        if(i == array.length - 1)
            return true;
        //recursive case
        if(array[i+1] != array[i] * 2)
            return false;
        else
            return isDouble(array, i);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `System.out.print(isDouble(new int[]{2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 5));` <- the last parameter here should be `0` and `return isDouble(array, i);` should be `return isDouble(array, i + 1);`

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive?

Comment: In this array {2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7} the value returned is false? if we have this array {2, 4, 8, 16, 32} the value to return to be true ?

Comment: @shmosel it is a recursion practice exercise, I did not want to use loops.

Comment: @YennyMuller it was returning true with the provided array. Literally returning true for everything. That's why I asked.

Comment: Hint: the real answer here: start small. Start with the smallest possible array you can test. And hint: ideally, the "public" method for this task ... only takes the array as parameter. Then you have a *private* method that also takes that additional starting index. As in: always think about potential "users" of your methods. They do not need to know that you have a recursive solution that requires that parameter. They just want to know "isDouble(someArray)". Finally: ask yourself what the method should return for an empty array, or one with only 1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method.

```
int[][] test = {{2,4}, {1},{2,3}, {6,12,24},{6,12,24,47},
        {2,4,8,16,32,64,128}, {}, null};
for (int[] t : test) {
     System.out.printf("%5s - %s%n", isDouble(t), Arrays.toString(t));
}
```

prints

```
 true - [2, 4]
false - [1]
false - [2, 3]
 true - [6, 12, 24]
false - [6, 12, 24, 47]
 true - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
false - []
false - null
```

You only need to pass the array.

- for each recursive call, copy the array sans the last element.
- make the call `ANDing` with current result (a single `false` comparison will return `false`).

```
public static boolean isDouble(int[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    int len = array.length;
    if (array[len-1] != array[len-2]*2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (array.length >=3 ) {
        return isDouble(Arrays.copyOf(array, len-1));       
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is one way to do it with passing an index of `0`. Using a call of `isDouble(array,0)` prints the same as above.  It is essentially the same as above except no array is being copied (so it is somewhat more efficient).

```
public static boolean isDouble(int[] array, int n) {
    if (array == null || array.length <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    int len = array.length;
    if (array[len-1] != array[len-2]*2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n < len-2) {
        return isDouble(array, n+1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

But the most efficient way would be a simple loop.  As soon as a false condition is exposed the result can be returned immediately with no `"unwinding"` of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct??

```
public class testRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(isDouble(new int[]{2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 5));

    }
    public boolean isDouble(int[] array,int i) {
            //base case
            if(i == 1) {
                if(array[i] == array[i-1] * 2)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }else {
                 if(isDouble(array, i-1)) {
                    if(array[i] == array[i-1] * 2)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return isDouble(array, i-1);
                 }else {
                     return false;
                 }
            }
        }
}
```